# Should i use Javascript redirection from crawlable to ajax website?

Tags: javascript, ajax, location, redirect

I'm developing an ajax website and i know that it is a good practice to keep all links as normal links (i.e "cats/") and, if javascript is enabled, ajaxify them ("#cats"). My website is fully crawlable by search engines and all pages are indexed.

My question is : when a user lands on the page "www.example.com/cats" through Google and if his browser is javascript enabled, is it safe to automatically redirect him to "www.example.com/#cats" with a simple javascript redirection (location.href = ...) ?

Comment: If /cats and /#cats don't lead to different content, there's no need to do this. Generally, the hash works with something like /animals#cats where #cats brings the user to the cats section of the /animals page.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that it is a good practice to keep all links as normal links (i.e "cats/")

It is.

> if javascript is enabled, ajaxify them ("#cats").

No, using fragment identifiers has [serious drawbacks](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs). It is good practise to either leave them as normal links or (**if** it is going to make a significant improvement to the usability of the site) Ajaxify them using [`pushState` and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#section_4).

Using `pushState` and friends makes the last paragraph of your question moot — since you only have one URI representing the content instead of two.

Comment: The only benefit to redirect my users is to maintain only one page (the website index) to deliver ajax content. All others pages are just automatically generated static pages.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. It results in the HTML of the page being loaded twice! The average user doesn't care about the address bar anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When your page loads, use javascript to check the url if `/cats` is present simply run your ajxy functions, there is no need to redirect.

Comment: Do you mean that when a user lands on the page /cats, he must stay here and navigation must be done with ajax from this page ? Does it mean that all my pages have to be based on the same template (with some static differences) ?

Comment: Url could be polluted : www.example.com/cats/#dogs... So HTML5 pushState is a good solution to make urls simplier and remove the #  : www.example.com/cats/#dogs to www.example.com/dogs. But i have to create a real static web page at www.example.com/dogs to welcome users who land on this page (from bookmark, external link...). Am i on the right way ?